# How to check the value entered in EditText is aplhanumeric or not?

Tags: android, validation, input, android-edittext

My application takes userid from user as input, the userid is alphanumeric i.e just the first character is (a-z), other part is numeric. How can I validate input of this type ( like G34555) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved issue by using simple `string` function `matches`

`String str="mystring";`

`str.matches("[a-zA-Z][0-9]+");`

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex. This should do it assuming the first letter can be upper or lower case:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z][0-9]+");

 Matcher m = p.matcher("some text you want");
 boolean isAlphaNum = m.matches();
```

Answer (score 3):

http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2009-11/msg02501.html seems like a more decent solution, it does not allow entering the chars that are not accepted.

Code from link:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```